# Pledger vs pledgor?

Tags: differences, synonyms

Are "**pledger**" and "**pledgor**" full synonyms? Or do these have different meanings regardles of the context?

I've found some discussions online that raise this question and tend to draw a difference between the two, but no serious proof was given so I'd rather disregard that.

Thank you.

Comment: *Debtor, **pledgor**, creditor,...* You'll probably find some people thinking that a ***pledger*** might specifically imply someone who makes some kind of pledge outside of the "legal" context, but I can't really see that as a useful distinction.

Comment: Belay that! They're subscription-only links to the full OED, but [pledgor](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/264903) has its own separate entry, defined as *only* having the legal sense. This is just one of 3 meanings (wherein "person who drinks to a well-wishing toast" is marked "obsolete") for the spelling [pledger](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/145638?redirectedFrom=pledger#eid).

Comment: Why not put all those meanings as an answer that I could accept? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entry from [Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pledgor) implies that ***pledger*** is simply a semantically-equivalent alternative to the more common ***pledgor***...

[image]

But here are a couple of links to the subscription-only full OED, where [pledgor](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/264903) has its own separate entry, and is defined as *only* having the legal sense.

That's just one of 3 meanings (wherein "person who drinks to a well-wishing toast" is marked "obsolete") for the spelling [pledger](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/145638?redirectedFrom=pledger#eid) (the third sense just being the more general *person who deposits something as a pledge*, not necessarily in a strictly legal context).